# Windows Remote Desktop licenses not being used

Tags: windows, remote-desktop-services

I'm part of a scientific lab and we have a Windows server we use for computation which we connect to using Remote Desktop. For a while, we didn't have any licenses purchased and it would let up to 2 people connect at the same time, but no more than that. As we have started getting more people who are all needing to use the server, we decided to buy user licenses so that more than 2 could connect at the same time. We purchased the licenses and I followed the instructions I could find to set them up and activate them. It shows in Administrative Tools->RD Licensing Manager that we have 5 licenses for "Windows Remote Desktop 2019 - Installed RDS Per User CAL", and I see the licensing service running in Server Manager. But when people try to connect it still only lets up to 2 people at a time and doesn't seem to be using the licenses (It says 0 have been issued). Does anyone know what I can do to figure out what the issue is?

Here is my Windows version information:

Edition: Windows Server 2019 Standard

Version: 1809

Build: 17763.973

Comment: Did you also install the Remote Desktop Session Host role? If not, you need to.

Comment: Yes, that role is installed. The two services I see running are Remote Desktop Licensing and Remote Desktop Services. Should I see one running for the session host role?